# Can my ISP know that I am using Tor if I am connecting to Tor via an SSH SOCKS5 proxy?

Tags: ssh, tor, isp, socks5

I created an SSH SOCKS tunnel that forwards connections from a local port to a remote server: `ssh -N -D 127.0.0.1:1234 me@example.com` (i.e. all connections to `127.0.0.1:1234` get forwarded to the `example.com` server). I then configured the Tor Browser to connect to Tor via the `127.0.0.1:1234` SOCKS5 proxy.

If I browse the web using the Tor Browser, can my ISP know that I am using Tor by looking at the SSH traffic between my computer and the `example.com` remote server?

Answer (score 1):

No, your ISP cannot tell you are using Tor.

Your ISP probably can tell you are using SSH as a proxy, but they have no way to identify what you are connecting on the other side of the proxy. They cannot tell if the endpoint is connecting direct to the internet, to a VPN server, or to Tor.

Comment: Can't the ISP use network traffic analysis to deduce that an SSH connection is carrying Tor data?

Comment: The ISP might not be able to tell that you're using TOR, but they can certainly tell from packet sizes and timings that you're *not* doing typical SSH things.

Comment: OP wants to know if ISP can tell they are using Tor, not if they are using SSH in unconventional ways.

Comment: @Flux no, they cannot. SSH traffic is encrypted, and ISP can only know OP is using SSH as a proxy, but not what kind of proxy OP is using.

Comment: @ThoriumBR Flux means packet size and timing analysis

Comment: Don't forget that SSH is the traffic ISP is looking at. Tor is encapsulated, so packet size is SSH packet size. Tor only takes over outside of the tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer is not really, but...

SSH can use a variety of [encryption algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Algorithms), chosen during the negotiation and setup phase. To my knowledge, these are all considered secure at this time, discounting attacks which are not against the protocol itself (eg, compromised executables, etc). So, the ISP will not be able to read your actual traffic to see what you are doing.

However, the SSH traffic pattern will be unusual for a typical SSH session. Anyone doing a frequency analysis will see that you are doing some kind of unusual activity, but will your ISP really care and take the time to do that analysis? Probably not.

If you are using a trusted version of the TOR browser, and don't have any other compromised binaries on your source or destination hosts, you are probably good for TOR.